# fa icon showing in new line

Tags: css, woocommerce, icons

I am trying to show fa icons with name of category in woocommerce wordpress products. I have figured it out to display them on a separate page but while showing them in the mega menu (Tweezers By Category), I am facing the problem that the FA icons are showing in the new line rather than showing before the name. You can check the live link [here](http://newsite.cealinetweezers.com/subcategories/).
Please check if anyone can help me here.

Comment: Add the icon in li or change the width of li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the icon inside each `<li>` element, example:

```
<li style="float:left;">
    <a href="http://newsite.cealinetweezers.com/tweezers/tweezers-by-category/aquarium-aquascaping-tweezers/">
        <i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i> 
        Aquarium &amp; Aquascaping Tweezers
    </a>
</li>
```

Wrapping the icon with a `span` and float left outside the `li` it's not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So the span tag is doing the trick here.

```
<li style="float:left;">
<a href="http://newsite.cealinetweezers.com/tweezers/tweezers-by-category/aquarium-aquascaping-tweezers/"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i> Aquarium &amp; Aquascaping Tweezers</a></li>
```